# Displaying an EBNF grammar using HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

What would be a good way to display an EBNF (or EBNF-like) grammar using HTML and CSS? I do not want to use the code tag. I want be able to display stuff aligned (viz. definition symbols ‘`=`’ with alternation symbols ‘`|`’, but also remarks).

Here’s an example of a grammar I want to display, only as a simple plain text:

```
<expression> = <integral>        
             | <variable>     (only variables of type Integer are allowed)
  <integral> = <digit>+
  <variable> = x | y | …      (any lower case latin letter)
…
```

The spacing within definitions like `<integral> = <digit>+`’ should be “as usual”, i.e. not compromised by some way of aligning the definition symbols (as would be the case when using tabulars for example).

Comment: Every instance of an EBNF grammar I've seen has been typeset in a fixed-width font using mostly a <pre> element. I haven't seen it set any other way.

Comment: @BoltClock Thanks, do you have an example at hand?

Comment: Usually html tags are written inside a html document by using &gt;(greater than) and &lt;(lower than) symbols. I think other EBNF symbols are standard supported so you don't need to tell the browser how to read them.

Comment: you can also use EBNF syntax highlighting in Nodepad++ Check my research on github: https://github.com/bluePlayer/practices/tree/master/ and download this highlighter: https://github.com/bluePlayer/practices/blob/master/EBNF/EBNF-NPP-Highlighter-version1.xml